# get html from td using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following jQuery. I am trying to fetch the html from td with having class "mainlisting" but i gives me "undefined" but if use other class i am able to get the value.

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var currentHTML = '<td><div class="listing-report-partner partner-id-559"><div class="print-icon print-partner-icon-sml" style="float: left"><img src="#"></div><div class="partner-name" style="float: none; margin-left: 45px;"> Facebook<br> <a class="viewlink" href="#" target="_blank">view listing</a></div></div></td><td class="mainlisting" width="100px"><span class="">Teste</span></td><td class="mainlisting" width="100px"><span class="notmatch">Test Address</span></td><td class="mainlisting" width="150px"><span class="">123-345-666</span></td><td width="50px"><div class="diagnostic-status status-alert"> <img src="#"><div class="listing-status"><span>Alert</span></div></div></td>';


name = jQuery('td.mainlisting:nth-child(1)', currentHTML).html();
alert(name);
Status = jQuery('.listing-status span',currentHTML).html();
alert(Status);


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it in one selector:

```
$('#mytable .customerIDCell').each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Please read my question...  my html is coming dynamic